# mysqli inserting first record in array twice

Tags: php, mysqli

I have an array with an unknown number of entries that need to be inserted into a MySQL DB table each time the script executes.  Thanks to another tip, I've successfully looped through the array and created the INSERT() statement for each entry, but the mysqli call to insert the records adds the first record twice, despite the $SQL query looking correct.

Here is the snippet:

```
foreach( $family_member as $key=>$value ){
        $first_name = str_replace("'","''",  $value['First']);
        $last_name = str_replace("'","''",  $value['Last']);
$SQL .="INSERT INTO family_roster(
        first_name,
        last_name,
        enter_date) VALUES(
        '$first_name',
        '$last_name',
        sysdate());";

$mysqli->multi_query($SQL);
```

The print_r for $SQL shows the INSERT() statement as expected:

```
INSERT INTO family_roster (
first_name,
last_name
enter_date) VALUES (
'Chris',
'Test'
sysdate());
INSERT INTO family_roster (
first_name,
last_name
enter_date) VALUES (
'Barbera',
'Test'
sysdate());
```

But the table shows the below results:

```
first_name | last_name | enter_date
--------------------------------------------
Chris      |Test       |2019-04-11 00:32:21
Chris      |Test       |2019-04-11 00:32:21
Barbera    |Test       |2019-04-11 00:32:21
--------------------------------------------
```

I can't find any reference in the webpage that is calling the script twice.  I assumed that the sysdate() would show different entry times but Im assuming its happening in less than a second.

Comment: no reason to use multi_query here, its usully bad regardless. you should be concatenating the values `INSERT INTO family_roster (first_name,last_name,enter_date) VALUES ('Chris','Test', sysdate()),('Barbera','Test' ...`

Comment: At some point I'm sure I'll get away from multi_query, but for the time being sinece the number of VALUES() that are being inserted are unknown Id have to rework the rest of the script to use the INSERT() statement once and the VALUES() multiple times based on the number of entries in the array.